# what is meant by 'publish' status in WooCoomerce?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have searched for statuses in Woocommerce documentation, but publish is not mentioned anywhere but rest api is returning me 'publish' status for some orders. Can anyone please tell me what is meant by 'publish' status? I think I have read somewhere that 'publish' status was omitted in woocommerce 2.2. But i still want to know what is meant by this status as I have to perform some calculations.

Comment: not for products, I'm getting publish status for orders :( I have mentioned in the question

Comment: "publish" status doesn't exist for "shop_order" post type… The first statuses for an order are "wc-pending" or "wc-on-hold" depending on the chosen payment method…